# Set Modal isOpen on props condition React js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have Modal in React Js which is working fine on  button click

Here is Modal

```
   <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={()=>setmodalIsOpen(false)}>
```

Here is Button on which click it is working

```
 <button onClick={()=>{setmodalIsOpen(true)}}>Open modal</button>
```

Here is my function or hook

```
const [modalIsOpen, setmodalIsOpen] = useState(false)
```

That is quite simple as  you can see but the task is -> with this working as weel
i want to open modal with a prop value which will be bollean(TRUE) .

Here is my prop

```
props.modalIsOpen
```

Its is containing the true value i have checked with console.

Now the question is where should i put condition to check
If there is true value in props please open the modal.
Else its working should be with hooks.

What i tried is

```
if(props.modalIsOpen){
    setmodalIsOpen(true)

  }
```

i know this is funny because it completely blanks my page. so i know this condition is now correct.
One more thing i am using function here on Modal page and class on the page from where props coming from.

Comment: Why not just pass the prop value to the `useState` as initial value?

Comment: ```if(props.modalIsOpen){
    setmodalIsOpen(true)
  }``` this seems completely unnecessary, from what I can read, you basically calling the same thing, if Modal is Open (true) set Modal Is Open with true again ? You will get infinite loop like that.

Comment: If by some chance you are talking about different prop (boolean value), you can add it to ```useState(props.modalIsOpen)``` or move the prop directly to ```<Modal isOpen={props.modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => props.changeHigherModal(true)} />```